# plotting prediction in trees of glm of partykit package

Tags: r, party

I am using `partykit` R package to perform a trees of poisson regression. I would like to have the estimated (`predict` with `type = "response"`) value at each. A reproducible example follows:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(
 x1 = runif(500),
 x2 = runif(500),
 exposure = runif(500, 1, 10)
)
d$claims <- rpois(500, lambda = exp(d$x1 > 0.5 & d$x2 > 0.5) * d$exposure)
m <- glmtree(claims ~ offset(log(exposure)) | x1 + x2,
  data = d, family = poisson)
```

I would like to plot the `predict(..., type = "response")` at the end of each leaf.

Comment: What kind of display do you want exactly? A boxplot (or histogram) of the predicted responses, collapsed over the differing offsets?

Comment: I want the expected value of the claims at each leaf. But, seeing the distribution (histogram) in addition, could be also fine.

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't clear to me. You have one intercept per leaf, approx 0, 0, and 1, as simulated, see `coef(m)`. The intercepts correspond to log(mu/exposure). Other equivalent formulations are log(mu) = intercept + log(exposure) or mu = exp(intercept) * exposure. Thus, mu increases with exposure. Therefore `plot(m)` displays the response (black circles) along with the fitted mu (red line) as a function of log-exposure. How exactly would you want to change the display?